# Change image onclick and stays clicked untill user restarts the app

Tags: java, android

When i click on a buttonimg it changes to what i want it to. but when i end the activity and go back to MainActivity then the buttonimg is set to its start state.

```
private Button Info ;
    public void openInformationActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InformationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

        Info=(Button) findViewById(R.id.infoBtn1);


Info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Info.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chkinfo);
                v.setSelected(true);
                openInformationActivity();
            }
        });
```

I expect after the 1st click on the image/button it stays changed .

Comment: Your activity might be re-create that's the reason you are your button in initial state.

Comment: How do you know the button image changes the first time. Looking at your code, I would expect the new activity to open instantaneously after the button click.

Comment: when i click on the button it changes and right after the new activity launches i can see it change

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the image resource files in an array, 0 and 1 and the values are saved inside the app as saved preferences. When  you first open the activity the image displayed is on array zero. When user clicks the button it will be changed to value 1 and that value overwrites the 0 in the shared preferences. This will enable you to have the same picture even after user ends activity